# Deleting all XML children in WiX

Tags: xml, xpath, wix

Is there a way in Wix to **delete all children** elements of a specific XML element?

I've tried the following:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="Perf_delete"
    File="[INSTALLFOLDER]unity.config"
    ElementPath='/configuration/unity/container/register[\[]@name="Perf"[\]]/constructor/param[\[]@name="machineNames"[\]]/array'
    VerifyPath="*"
    Action="delete"
    Node="element"
    On="install"/>
```

Here I'm specifying:

- ElementPath - to point to the element itself
- VerifyPath - * to specify all the children elements

But this deletes only the first child.

There is obviously a workaround to delete the element itself, and then recreate it, but it's very tedious with all the attributes and namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the parent element and then create it again without adding new nested child elements. There is no way to remove multiple child elements from a parent element with just one util:XmlConfig declaration.