# WiX: how to remove all node elements of same type with no condition

Tags: xml, xpath, wix

Assume we have the following xml snippet:

```
<Computers>
  <PC name="1" />
  <PC name="2" />
</Computers>
```

I know that I can remove a particular node with the declaration like this:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="DeletePCs" 
                Action="delete" 
                On="install" 
                File="[#myfile.config]" 
                Node="element" 
                ElementPath="/Computers" 
                VerifyPath="/Computers/PC[\[]@name='2'[\]]" 
                Sequence="1" />
```

which successfully removes the second PC node. However, if I want to remove both nodes with just one XmlConfig declaration I cannot. I tried different combinations of VerifyPath with * or leaving empty, but it either does nothing or fails.

Is there a way to do that or I need to do it one by one with as many declarations as many elements need to be removed?

Comment: By the way if I use VerifyPath="/Computers/*" then it removes only the first PC node under Computers.

Comment: Seems like deleting the parent then recreate is the only way? [Deleting all XML children in WiX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268467/deleting-all-xml-children-in-wix)

Comment: That's what I thought too. But, if the parent has some other type of elements too then all will be gone. I even tried VerifyPath="/Computers/PC[\[]@name[\]]"  which should select all PC elements that have the 'name' attribute, but it removes only the first PC element. Looks like the selection is correct it's just a XmlConfig declaration is intended for one action on one element only.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being there is no known way to remove certain type of elements from a parent element. One can remove all child elements of a parent element by removing the parent element and adding it back again with no children elements nested in it (as a workaround). However, if selective type of elements are needed to be removed and some other type of elements to be left under the parent then there is no way for now, other than removing the selected elements one by one since the util:XmlConfig node declaration with removal action in WiX is capable to remove only one element from an xml file.